# Set the return type of the Django response as a list of objects

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

How to format the DRF response as a list of objects ?

Here are my models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def get_all_cars(self):
       # get car list
       return cars

class Cars(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    year = models.IntegerField()
```

Serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email')

class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Cars
        fields = ('name', 'year')
```

ViewSets:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Users.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = default_permission_classes

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'car':
            return CarSerializer
        return UserSerializer

    @action(detail=True)
    def cars(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        all_cars = self.get_object().get_all_cars()
        serializer=CarSerializer(all_cars, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

Here on calling cars endpoint in User rest API, I get a list of cars in the following format:

```
[
    {
        "name": "civic",
        "year": "2004",
    },
    {
        "name": "city",
        "year": "2005",
    }
]
```

Which is the expected response from this endpoint. The issue is the serializer class (return type of the response). I want it the class to be a list of Car objects instead the return type is a Car object.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Edit:

Currently in the swagger UI, the endpoint response's description is

```
Car {
  name: string
  year: integer
}
```

Instead I want it to be:

```
[Car {
  name: string
  year: integer
}]
```

Hope I could make my question clear.

Comment: JSON has no knowledge of classes. It has only "objects".

Comment: @naruto Would you please write, how is your expected response look like?

Comment: @Hasan, I just updated my question. Thanks

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that's a good point, my question wasn't clear previously. I updated my question. Thanks